# Which is better Rest or PWA for app development

Tags: magento2

There few screenshot image for mobile apps that i want to build as app.I want to know should i use PWA and make app using or just go with simple rest Api. I am novice in magento world.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare **PWA** with **REST**, as REST is an API, and PWA is APP development which can use REST API.

Although PWA is a good approach

- App-Like Look and Feel
- Fast Installation
- Better Performance
- Platform- and Device-Agnosticism
- No Updating Issues
- Seamless Offline Operation
- No Dependence on App Distribution Services
- Push Notification Functionality
- Enhanced Security

For comparison you check GraphQL and REST API.

**Main Difference between GraphQL and REST:**

A REST API is an architectural concept for network-based software. GraphQL, on the other hand, is a query language, a specification, and a set of tools that operates over a single endpoint using HTTP. In addition, over the last few years, REST has been used to make new APIs, while the focus of GraphQL has been to optimize for performance and flexibility.

**REST API Request Sample**
You can see, it requires 3 different API to get the data
[image]

**GraphQL Request Sample**
Whereas GraphQL just need one request to get relevant data, you can even specify which columns you need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im developing the app with magento rest api. There're a lot of problems with magento default api. I have to create new APIs to make my app functions are same with the web. Such as Social login, Homepage blocks, Catalog with more details, convert guest cart to logged in customer cart,...

I saw other company apps.They use only login and reward point api.And just open the whole webpage inside app to let customer view catalog and buy it.